# TabsIcons disappear after my refresh viewPager by adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, adapter

**Problem !**

I'm using a TabLayout with icon
that's my Adapter

```
public class ViewPagerIconsAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerIconsAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
      mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And this is how I use my adapter to add fragments in ViewPager and showing icons in my TabLayout

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
setupTabIcons();
```

**setupViewPager method**

```
adapter = new ViewPagerIconsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1());
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2());
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3());
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**setupTabIcons method**

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
```

the problem is when I use notifyDataSetChanged to refresh my viewPager all icons disappear.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Can someone have an idea??

Comment: so your icons are fixed and will not be changed?
as per code above

Comment: i call my method setupTabIcons method after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but there is no effect, icons dissapear

Comment: tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,false);
try this

Answer (score 1):

If your icons are fixed
Try this:
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,false);

Comment: no this doesn't seem to do anything, and it would usually have been set previously I think? so it shouldn't be set again